# How can I remove the special character words from a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I would like to remove all the special character words from a string, not a special characters. 
For example, words like Sund@y, He!!o, ^stars, creat!vity

I have found lots of regex on removing special characters but cannot create a regex having special character words.

```
String example = "This is Sund@y."
```

Expected output:

```
result : This is
```

Comment: So you want to remove the whole word, not just the character?

Comment: @MichaelPickett yes, that is correct.

Comment: find words with special characters and remove them. What's the problem?

Comment: @Gaur93 - How is your comment helpful to *anyone*?

Comment: @TheLostMind I am asking him the problem he is facing in removing the whole word.

Comment: @Gaur93 I can do it the hard way which is splitting the words and use string.contains to look for the special characters and remove it. However, I would like to know if there is any regular expression for that so that I can use either removeAll or pattern to extract all the words at once.

Comment: @ChitKhine - Show us what you've tried :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with a simple one-liner that doesn't require you to manually perform string-splicing:

```
String result = target.replaceAll("[^ ]*\\p{Punct}[^ ]*", "");
```

Note the double backslashes - because we need to represent a single backslash in the string (to produce the regex token `\p{Punct}`), we have to escape the backslash.

Comment: working perfectly. but the regex in the previous query is removing the @y before this function.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yourString = " This is Sund@y.";
    String[] words = yourString.split("\\s+");
    String newWords = "";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[@^!]");

    for (String word : words) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
        boolean b = m.find();
        if (b != true) {
            newWords += word + " ";
        }

    }
    System.out.println(newWords);
}
```

Input: `This is Sund@y.` 
Output:  `This is`